# Selecting column-values to be changed by their dynamic column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple datetime columns, but they have different formats. I want to normalize them. However, the respective column names are dynamic, only with a piece of them being constants, e.g. `xxx last updated` and `yyy updated`, where the string-piece `updated` always indicates the column are type datetime.

How could I dynamically `.apply(pd.to_datetime)` to all these columns?

All solutions I found so far in other threads require indicating the specific column names.

Comment: can you provide an example of input and output that you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Column names are an index, so you can filter them just like rows.

```
cols_to_update = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('updated')]
df[cols_to_update] = df[cols_to_update].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

---

A quick breakdown:

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['non interesting', 'xxx last updated', 'yyy updated'], dtype='object')

>>> df.columns.str.contains('updated')
array([ False,  True,  True])

>>> df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('updated')]
Index(['xxx last updated', 'yyy updated'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!