# Select only columns that contain specific character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df of numbers initially stored as all type str where sometimes the data in the columns is stored as a percent but **its not always the same columns**. I don't know which columns will be a percent or will be a number. If its stored as a percent I need to convert it to a decimal.

How can I find which columns are percent and then convert only those columns to decimals

An example

```
name  date  col1  col2  col3  col4
a     9/17  1.23  4.90% 3.00  100.00%
b     9/17  2.00  6.10% 5.00  253.90%
c     9/17  6.71  7.90% 7.00  98.00%
```

Desired output:

```
name  date  col1  col2  col3  col4
a     9/17  1.23  0.049 3.00  1.00
b     9/17  2.00  0.061 5.00  2.539
c     9/17  6.71  0.079 7.00  0.98
```

I tried

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
df.iloc[:,2:]=df.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('%').astype(float)/100, axis=1)
```

But this but it is setting all the columns that are type float to nan. If the columns are all type str at first the second line will divide all the values by 100 which I don't want. Therefore I need to find and select only the entire columns that have %

Something like

```
df.loc[:,df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("%"), axis=1)]
```

except this will give you a index by multi-dimensional key error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting column-values to be changed by their dynamic column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63760411/selecting-column-values-to-be-changed-by-their-dynamic-column-names)

Comment: No, its not based on the column names at all its based on the column values

Comment: Sorry I thought I deleted my comment right after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using `filter` and `select_dtypes` to find the columns:

```
cols = df.filter(like="col").select_dtypes("object").columns
```

Alternatively you can extract 1 row and find `%`:

```
cols = df.columns[df.loc[0].astype(str).str.endswith("%")]
```

Both will get you the column names.

```
df[cols] = df[cols].replace("%", "", regex=True).astype(float)/100

print (df)

  name  date  col1   col2  col3   col4
0    a  9/17  1.23  0.049   3.0  1.000
1    b  9/17  2.00  0.061   5.0  2.539
2    c  9/17  6.71  0.079   7.0  0.980
```

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```py
import numpy as np

def percent_to_float(percent: str) -> float:
    return float(percent[:-1])/100

df.select_dtype(object).apply(np.vectorize(percent_to_float))
```

This takes all columns with `dtype=object` (string data is stored with `dtype=object` in `pandas`) and applies a function that converts a percentage string like `4.5%` to a float like `0.045`.